# Chromedriver was unable to start correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium chrome driver which is running in a loop and opens 6k URLs and copies some details. Actually i am using multithreading.pool.ThreadPool method to do the work. But after almost 3k URLs, I am getting error
Chrome was unable to start correctly (0xc000012d). Any help plz.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, this and also `0xc0000142` error dialog boxes were appearing because I ran out of page file space. I.e., not physical memory ("In use" field in the below screenshot) - just a half of it is used. But specifically, the page file: "Committed" field in the screenshot below.
[image]
You can read the details about the differences [here](https://superuser.com/questions/971967/why-is-my-committed-memory-so-much-higher-than-my-actual-ram-space/974010). Basically, each Python process running Selenium was reserving ~2GB of page file space for me, while it was actually using only ~200MB.

So the easiest solution is to increase the page file size. I did so from 204GB to 320GB, now my Chromes run smoothly.